# GMS2 - Game showing the wrong object

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

I'm making an Undertale fangame in GMS2 and i have a problem with my Game:
It's supposed to show this:[image: obj_next_room]

But it shows this:

[image: stretched obj_torcar]

obj_next_room code:
[image]

The car (obj_torcar) doesn't have code.
Room creation code:

```
if audio_exists(26) then if not audio_is_playing(26) then BGM_Play(1, 26, true)
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: You might want to check if the object also doesn't have any object-specific code inside the room. if you double click on the object in the room, it has a "object creation code" or something similair, maybe that could change the sprite as well

Comment: @Steven it doesn't

Comment: The first two screenshot feature different backgrounds/tilesets. Are they actually the same room?

Comment: @liggiorgio yes, first screenshot is in the editor and the second in game

Comment: Your screenshots are too narrow, you may have cropped something that could help us understand better what's going on. Mind including a wider view of the room, both in-editor and in-game? It'd be nice to see how other objects interact with the NR object, if any.

Comment: UPDATE: i used another object and it works, but now i made an object named "trigger_warp_init" and it has the same problem

Comment: @Chateauvisionn Can you please tell us how you're scaling the *next room* object? Also, comments are for brief explanations: changes in your problem and partial solutions should be included in your question by editing it instead.